# Is there a way to spell check?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is there a way to spell check? If not I think it would be a valuable add on feature.

Answer (score 5):

See [Please add a spell checker to the markdown editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3932/please-add-a-spell-checker-to-the-markdown-editor).

Essentially, as of now it's best to keep the spell checking in the browser. If you're using Chrome or Firefox, spell checking is built-in.

And considering the technical implementation is far from easy, I would imagine this is a satisfactory solution.